# JSP Response: Adding Header Info

Tags: java, jsp

I have a jsp with this code:

```
response.addHeader("Authorization", "Basic aW50ZWc6VGVzVCMxMjM0Cg==");
response.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic aW50ZWc6VGVzVCMxMjM0Cg==");
response.sendRedirect("https://example.com/gl/dtpadd.do?");
```

The page https://example.com/gl/dtpadd.do requires authentication.

When I use Google Chrome Postman with Authorization header, it works fine. Whereas, from JSP it prompts for password.

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: You're trying to add an Authorization header to your response, but it has to be added to the request sent to example.com instead. sendRedirect() makes the client (browser) send another request to a new URL. AFAIK there is no way to trigger that explicitly. (Well, you could add the credentials to the URL like `response.sendRedirect("https://user:password@example.com/gl/dtpadd.do?");` if that works for you.)

Comment: Adding user and password to the URL didn't work.

Comment: Adding user and password to the URL didn't work in IE11 but worked in Chrome. Any idea how to make this work on IE11. Thx

Comment: Looks like IE doesn't support this any more: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/834489